How to make the profile likelihood model for estimation?
I tried to make the age estimation model using the chemical compound results from The soil. Initially, I used the multivariable regression model. However, the reviewer highly recommend using the profile likelihood instead of regression model due to the overfitting problem. I learnt The profile likelihood method. I would like to make the estimation model Just using the profile likelihood. However, I found that making estimation model Just using profile likelihood is impossible. It needs to make the basic function (like linear model) then applying the likelihood.
But I also heard that no one applied the likelihood into the linear regression model because the result is identical and it is more complicate. I’m sure I’m in the wrong way. But I do not catch how to approach the profile likelihood method to develop the estimation model.
Could you help me to borrow your brain? If you have any advice, please let me know.
This is the original code that I used to make the estimation model.
Com1<- c(-0.91475561, -1.39706018, -3.88102766, -2.15068888, 3.36007488, 8.09092947, 5.10511848, 4.98272449)
Com2<-c(-0.642793922, -0.481519952, 0.545645985, -0.151149253, -0.812447751, -0.363022089, 4.288690815, 0.523588945)
Age <-c(20, 21, 22, 23, 93, 94, 95, 96)
ChemicalResult<-data.frame(Age, Com1, Com2)
RegModel <-lm(Age~., data = ChemicalResult)
ExC1<-c(0.00169)
ExC2<-c(0.94)
Chem<-data.frame (ExC1, ExC2)
names(Chem)<-c("Com1","Com2")
Expred<-predict(PCR, Chem)


Nobody will be able to help you finding the concentrated likelihood for your problem if all you post is R code. How does your likelihood function look like?
